# Как создать всплывающее боковое окно?

Tags: html, css

Хочу сделать всплывающее боковое окно, а с помощью чего и как это сделать — не знаю. Должно выглядеть так изначально:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При нажатии так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Только зачем вы меню скрываете вместе с блоком, вы потом его обратно не вызовите.

```js
$('.button').click(function(){
 $('.container').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.container {
 height: 300px; 
 background: black;
}
.button {
 width: 50px;
 height: 50px; 
 background: yellow;
}
.side__menu {
 height: 300px;
 width: 200px;
 background: red;
 transition: ease-in-out .3s;
}
.container.active .side__menu {
 transform: translate(-200px);
 transition: ease-in-out .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
<div class='button'>
  click
</div>
<div class='side__menu'>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```